# How to solve key issue of API

Tags: r, api

Hi I try to call some data using API but it shows error message of "invalid key". But In the function I didn't figure out where I can input my key. The code is shown below:

```
sahie_years <- getCensus(
  name = "timeseries/healthins/sahie",
  vars = c("NAME", "PCTUI_PT"), 
  region = "state:01", 
  time = "from 2006 to 2018")
head(sahie_years)
```

Can anybody have some ideas?

Comment: Where does the `getCensus` function some from? Are you using a non-base R package? Does that function have documentation?

Comment: @MrFlick is right, you need to add some more detailed info - I just assumed you are using the `censusapi` package, so answered with that assumption, but you should specify what libraries you are using

Answer (score 2):

See documentation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/censusapi/vignettes/getting-started.html) for setting up your API key.

You need to sign up for an API key [here](https://api.census.gov/data/key_signup.html).

Once you've done that you can either specify your API key by setting an environment variable using `Sys.setenv(CENSUS_KEY="YOUR_CENSUS_KEY_GOES_HERE")`, or
just set it directly in your `getCensus` call by adding the argument `key = "YOUR_CENSUS_KEY_GOES_HERE"`.

For API keys in general, it is often easiest to set them in a .Renviron file, which will make them available in each session using `Sys.getenv`.